# Why is chrome giving me a TypeError when finding largest number in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following code to find the largest number in an array:

```
function max(input) {
 var maxNum = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i <= input.length; i++) {
     if(maxNum < input[i]) {
         maxNum = input[i];
        }
    }
    return maxNum;
}
max([1, 2, 3, 7]);
```

When I run it in Google Chrome, Edge, or Firefox I get:

```
max.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at max (max.js:20)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

but when I run it on [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=display) for JavaScript, I get the correct results without any syntax error.

Comment: I copy and pasted it into my chrome console and got 7 returned to me without error.

Comment: And `Chromium Version 65.0.3325.181` no error!

Comment: You're probably calling `max` with no parameters somewhere else in your code/console.

Comment: Also the check should be `i < input.length` not `i <= input.length`.

Comment: Tip: Arrays are zero based. so change `for(var i = 0; i <= input.length;i++)` to `for(var i = 0; i < input.length;i++)`. (just smaller than)

Comment: Your solution would fail my interview test I used to give. `max([-1, -2]);`

Comment: You might be calling max function from somewhere else without an array as its parameter.

Comment: Learn to debug: `for(var i = 0; i <= input.length; i++) { console.log(i, input[i])`

Comment: Thank you all, I upgraded chrome and edge to the latest and now it works.No errors.

Answer (score -1):

that type of error is very explicit

it says that it can't calculate a length of a undefined property.

If you watch closely, your iterations is like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= input.length; i++) {
```

you pass a array with 4 elements, but the indexes go from **0 to 3** input.length gives you the size of the array that is **4**, so when you do input.length for the last element if fails

take the equal out:

```
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This is simply not true.